# Why is "Show page source" not available in (my) WebKit?

Tags: webkit

I've downloaded v. 537.6+ of WebKit for Mac OS, and am running it on 10.8.  (No programming here, just being a web developer looking for the WebKit web inspector.)  Everything's fine, except the "Show page source" option in the Develop menu is grayed out when I'm on even the most, and I can't find any way to enable it.   I"m very puzzled -- is there something else I need to do to get it enabled?  Is there something else going on?  Is this how it's supposed to be?

#### Developer Menu

[image]

#### The contextual menu:

[image]

Comment: What appears in the contextual menu when you right-click on the page ?

Comment: If I'm off in a sort of useless corner of a page, I getsBack / Reload page / Open in dashboard... / Save page as... / Print page / Inspect element.  Other things show up if I'm hovering over text or an image, of course.

Comment: What happens when you click on inspect element ?

Comment: The usual webkit inspector opens up in a pane at the bottom of the window.  All that stuff works fine; it's just that I can't get into a full window containing the page's source.

Comment: I uploaded the screenshots of menus. It uses up-to-date webkit nightly.

Comment: Thx.  My puzzlement continues, but, as noted before, I can now do what I want with stock Safari, so I think I'm moving on...

Comment: Try to press Command-U.

Comment: Been there, tried that, doesn't work.  But thanks...

Answer (score 1):

WebKit is not a full browser - only a rendering engine. Typically things like "view source", the back/forward buttons, address bar, preferences menus etc. are implemented at the browser level, outside of WebKit. However WebKit probably provides a minimum implementation of these for testing purposes, which presumably excludes 'view source' (which I can imagine isn't really essential for testing).

If you want to play with a full browser, you can't compile all of Safari, but you could try compiling Chromium instead which provides all that stuff. Note however Chromium is now using Blink instead of WebKit.

Comment: Well, no, not so much -- the WebKit I was referring to is the Safari developer build at http://webkit.org, of which I have the 5/16/13 version (I think, anyway -- 8536.29.13, 537+).  After enabling the Developer menu, I get a grayed-out Show Page Source command, and the hotkey doesn't do anything -- just like on stock Safari after having enabled the Develop menu.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable [WebInspector](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/WebInspector) to view the source.

Answer (score -1):

The webkit you have is a very old one. I've tried downloading it to help with your question, but it won't even run on OSX 10.8.3. You can always get the current latest build of WebKit here:http://www.webkit.org [edit: I see this question was asked in 2012, so that would explain why it's an old version.]

However you say you are "a web developer looking for the WebKit web inspector" and you are running OSX 10.8.  In that case you can perhaps just use the standard Safari that's already on your Mac.  You need to do the following to show the Develop menu. And then you have the "Page Source" item you are expecting.

1. Launch Safari.
2. Open Safari’s Preferences by selecting ‘Safari, Preferences’ from the menu.
3. Click the ‘Advanced’ tab labeled.
4. Place a check mark next to ‘Show Develop menu in menu bar.’

Comment: See above comment....  However, I'm now remembering what's weird about this -- I DO get the View Source command in the official Apple Safari release, but not in the WebKit nightly builds.  I started using WebKit for some development work because there were features that hadn't been incorporated into the official Safari release, but they're there now, so I guess my immediate problem has been solved.  It still feels like there's something wrong, though...